# Derivation of Distribution Function (CDF) of Gamma Distribution using Poisson Process

Tags: probability-distributions, poisson-process, gamma-distribution

I found the following result on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_distribution#Characterization_using_shape_k_and_scale_.CE.B8) relating to the CDF of the Gamma Distribution when the shape parameter is an integer. (*Note: there is a slight difference on how I have defined the scale parameter and how it is given on the Wikipedia page*)
$$
X \sim Gamma(n, \lambda)\\
f_x(x; n, \lambda) = \frac{e^{-\lambda}x^{n-1}}{\lambda^n \Gamma(n)}\\
F(x;n,\lambda) = 1 - \sum_{i=0}^{n-1}{\frac {(\lambda x)^i} {i!}e^{-\lambda x}}
$$

Can we prove the above result by considering a *Poisson Process* with parameter $\lambda$?

I reasoned this out as follows: (I believe this is not a very rigorous proof)

> Let $X_t$ denote the Poisson Process with parameter $\lambda$. We know that:
>   $$
> X_t \sim Poi(\lambda t)
> $$
>
> Also, denote by $T_i$ the inter-arrival time between the ${(i-1)}^{th}$ and $i^{th}$ occurrence of the event. Now, since we are dealing with a Poisson Process with parameter $\lambda$ so, $T_i$'s are $iid$ $Exp(\lambda)$ distributed.
>
> As a result,
>   $$
> \sum_{i=1}^{n}{T_i} \sim Gamma(n,\lambda)
> $$
>   Now,
>   $$
> \begin{align}
> \mathbb{P}[\sum_{i=1}^{n}{T_i} > t] &= Pr[by\ time\ t\ less\ than\ n\ events\ have\ occured]\\
> &= \mathbb{P}[X_t < n]\\
> &= \sum_{x=0}^{n-1}{\frac {(\lambda t)^x} {x!}e^{-\lambda t}}
> \end{align}
> $$
>
> Finally, subtracting the above value from $1$ gives us the CDF in the required form.

Is this reasoning technically correct? I would highly appreciate if anyone could suggest a different method.

Comment: The Wikipedia article does not say $f_x(x; n, \lambda).$ That notation is nonsense. $f_X(x; n, \lambda),$ on the other hand, might make sense. Failure to attend to this distinction between $X$ and $x$ will render you unable to understand some routine exercises for undergraduates and other things.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Yes, you are correct, except that you are using $X_i$ in the place of $T_i$.

If $\{X_t,t \geq 0\}$, is a Poisson process with intensity parameter $\lambda$, then the  inter-arrival times  $T_{1},T_{2},\cdots$ are  are iid exponential random variables with mean $1/\lambda$.

If $W_n$ denotes the waiting time for the $n^{th}$ event to occur, then
$$W_{n}=T_{1}+T_{2}+\cdots +T_{n}$$.

Then, we have, $W_{n}>t \ \ \Leftrightarrow \ \ X_t<n$.

$$P\{W_{n}>t\}=P\{X_t<n\} = \sum_{x=0}^{n-1}\dfrac{(\lambda t)^{x}}{x!}e^{\lambda t}$$

Comment: Thank you for identifying the error. I have now corrected it in my question.

Comment: @L.V.Rao A presentation detail : I have taken the liberty to transform $P\{W_{n}>t\} \Leftrightarrow P\{X_t<n\}$ into $W_{n}>t \Leftrightarrow X_t<n$.

Comment: @Jean Marie Thank you for the correction.