# Cumulative Distribution function of a poisson distribution in terms of it's parameter.

Tags: probability, poisson-distribution

Let $P(X=n) = \lambda^ne^{-\lambda}/n!$ which is a Poisson distribution. I need to find the cumulative distribution function.
The first think that comes to my mind is summation across n from $-\infty$ to $\infty$. But the answer is in terms of integration of $\lambda$.

$P(X\le n) = 1-\int_{0}^{\lambda} (x^ne^{-x}/n!)dx$

How do we change that integration over x into integration over $\lambda$?

Comment: Where are you getting this answer from?

Comment: This is because the CDF of Poisson distribution is related to that of a Gamma distribution. Hence the incomplete gamma function.

Comment: Plenty of duplicates: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/467341/question-about-connection-between-poisson-and-gamma-distributions,https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1960133/proving-the-gamma-poisson-relationship-using-induction,https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2205444/derivation-of-distribution-function-cdf-of-gamma-distribution-using-poisson-pr

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Poisson distribution takes values $n \in \{0,1,2,\dotsc\}$ with probability $P(X=n) = e^{-\lambda} \lambda^n / n! =: p_n(\lambda) $, so the cumulative distribution function is
$$ P(X \leq n) = \sum_{k=0}^n e^{-\lambda} \frac{\lambda^k}{k!} = \sum_{k=0}^n p_k(\lambda) . $$
This sum has a rather weird property (which admittedly one would not spot unless one is familiar with particular differential equations): if we differentiate with respect to $\lambda$, we find that
$$ p_k'(\lambda) = \frac{d}{d\lambda} e^{-\lambda} \frac{\lambda^k}{k!} = - e^{-\lambda} \frac{\lambda^k}{k!} + e^{-\lambda} \frac{\lambda^{k-1}}{(k-1)!} = -p_k + p_{k-1} , $$
and $p_0'(\lambda) = 0$. Thus,
$$ \frac{d}{d\lambda} P(X \leq n) = \sum_{k=0}^n p_n'(\lambda) = 0 + \sum_{k=1}^n (p_{k-1}(\lambda)-p_k(\lambda)) . $$
If we write out the sum, we see that it telescopes, leaving only $-p_n$. Hence, by the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus,
$$ P(X \leq n) = P(X \leq n)(\lambda=0) - \int_0^{\lambda} p_n(x) \, dx . $$
The first term is $1$ since a Poisson distribution with parameter $0$ takes the value $0$ with probability $1$, the second is the integral given in the answer.

---

Of course everyone is wondering why you would want to do this. I think the simplest reason is, if you want to estimate the probability of being larger than $n$, it is much easier to do this with the expression $\int_0^{\lambda} p_n $ than the infinite sum $\sum_{k=n+1}^{\infty} p_k$.

Comment: Where is $dx$ in the last integral?

Comment: For functions of one variable that are written as a set of symbols, it's quite common to omit the integration variable: it's redundant. For example, 
$$\int_0^x \sin = 1-\cos{x}$$
is completely unambiguous. Similarly, if I define a "squaring" function by $s(x) = x^2$, $ \int_a^b s = (b^3-a^3)/3 $, but you need the $dx$ if the function is written as an explicit expression containing $x$: $\int_a^b x^2 \, dx = (b^3-a^3)/3$.

Comment: I follow till $\frac {d}{d\lambda} P(X /le {n} ) = - p_n$ . How do you proceed with the next step?

Comment: $ \int_a^b f'(x) \, dx = f(b)-f(a) $, so $ f(b) = f(a) + \int_a^b f'(x) \, dx $. In this case, $f$ is $P(X \leq n)$, regarded as a function of $\lambda$.

Comment: In the telescoping sum, for k = 1, where did $p_0(\lambda)$ go? That’s non zero right?