# Show that $p(0 ; \lambda) + ... + p(n; \lambda) = \frac1{n!} \int_{\lambda}^\infty e^{-x}x^n dx,$ where $p(k; \lambda)$ is a Poisson distribution.

Tags: probability, probability-theory, self-learning

> Prove 
>   $$p(0 ; \lambda) + ... + p(n; \lambda) = \frac1{n!} \int_{\lambda}^\infty e^{-x}x^n dx.$$

$p(k; \lambda)$ is a Poisson distribution with parameter $\lambda$. The left side is equal to $\frac{1}{n!}\sum_{k=0}^n \frac{\lambda^k}{k!}e^{-\lambda} n!$. Thus, $\sum_{k=0}^n \frac{\lambda^k}{k!}e^{-\lambda} n! = \int_{\lambda}^\infty e^{-x}x^n dx$. I found that the right hand side look close to the gamma function: $\Gamma(n+1) = \int_0^\infty e^{-x}x^n dx$, and $n! = \Gamma(n+1)$. I was trying to find a way to use these to solve this question, but I couldn't. I appreciate if you give some help.

Comment: Isn't $\sum\limits_{k=0}^{n} p(k;\lambda)$ just $e^{-\lambda}\sum\limits_{k=0}^{n}\frac{\lambda^{k}}{k!}$ ?

Comment: I edited. Yes you are right.

Comment: I guess you may prove it by induction. One key step is integration by part on the integral. This is a key relationship in Poisson process, between the number of arrivals and the arrival time.

Comment: Possible duplicate : you find answers or references [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1960133/proving-the-gamma-poisson-relationship-using-induction), [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/467341/question-about-connection-between-poisson-and-gamma-distributions), [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2969484/how-did-they-get-this-proof-for-cdf-of-gamma-distribution), [etc](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3361023/cumulative-distribution-function-of-a-poisson-distribution-in-terms-of-its-para)...

Comment: You can get a vertically centred ellipsis with proper spacing to surrounding binary operators like $+$ using `\cdots`.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2205444/321264

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$p(k;\lambda)=e^{-\lambda}\frac{\lambda^k}{k!}$ for $k=0,1,2,\dots$.

$\frac{1}{0!}\int_{\lambda}^{\infty}e^{-x}x^0dx 
=\int_{\lambda}^{\infty}e^{-x}dx = e^{-\lambda} = p(0;\lambda)$

$\frac{1}{1!}\int_{\lambda}^{\infty}e^{-x}x^1dx 
=\int_{\lambda}^{\infty}e^{-x}xdx = e^{-\lambda}+\lambda e^{-\lambda} = p(0;\lambda)+p(1;\lambda)$

So, the equality holds up to $n=2$. Assume it holds for $n$. Apply integration by parts for $n+1$ letting $u=\frac{x^{n+1}}{(n+1)!}$ and $dv=e^{-x}$. We then get $\int udv = uv - \int vdu$:

\begin{eqnarray*}
\int_{\lambda}^{\infty}e^{-x}\frac{x^{n+1}}{(n+1)!}dx
&=&
\frac{e^{-x}}{-1}\frac{x^{n+1}}{(n+1)!}\Big|_{\lambda}^{\infty} 
+ \int_{\lambda}^{\infty}e^{-x}\frac{x^n}{n!}dx\\
&=&
e^{-\lambda}\frac{\lambda^{n+1}}{(n+1)!} + p(n;\lambda)+\cdots+p(0;\lambda)\\
&=&
p(n+1;\lambda) + p(n;\lambda)+\cdots+p(0;\lambda)\\
\end{eqnarray*} 
so the result holds by induction.