# Relating probabilities between different probability spaces

Tags: probability, probability-theory

I am trying to relate the following random experiments.
The first experiment involves tossing a coin until $n$ heads have appeared.
The second experiment involves tossing a coin $N$ times.
Let $H$ be the random variable representing the number of heads obtained in the second experiment.
My claim is that the probability that you get at least $n$ heads in the $N$ trials is equal to the probability that the number of trials in the first experiment, $X$, is less than or equal to $N$ i.e.
$$\mathbb{P}(H \geq n) = \mathbb{P}(X\leq N)$$
Intuitively this makes sense to me however I do not know how to justify this claim, considering that the random variables $H, X$ are defined on different probability spaces altogether.

Comment: Here is an example illustrating what you are looking for : the connection between Poisson (discrete) distribution and gamma or exponential (continuous) distribution : https://math.stackexchange.com/q/467341/305862. Indeed the probability spaces are different 
 : resp.$\mathbb{N}$ and $\mathbb{R^+}$.

Comment: See [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2205444/305862) or [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1960133/305862) as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your claim is correct. The probability that we get at least $n$ number of heads
when we toss $N$ times is
$$\mathbb P(H\ge n)=\sum_{h=n}^N{N\choose h}p^h(1-p)^{N-h}\,.$$
Instead of calculating $\mathbb P(X\le N)$ it is easier to calculate the probability
of $\mathbb P(X>N)$ which is the one that in the first $N$ tosses we have only $n-1$ heads at most:
$$\mathbb P(X>N)=\sum_{h=0}^{n-1}{N\choose h}p^h(1-p)^{N-h}$$
Obviously it is $\mathbb P(H\ge n)+\mathbb P(X>N)=1$ from which
$$
\mathbb P(H\ge n)=\mathbb P(X\le N)
$$
follows.

A joint probability space $\Omega$ on which this all works formally could be the space of infinite sequences of zeroes and ones: $\Omega=\{0,1\}^\mathbb N\,.$ Each $\omega\in\Omega$ is then a sequence $\omega_1,\omega_2,...$ of zeroes and ones
and
$$
H(\omega)=\sum_{i=1}^N\omega_i\,,\quad X(\omega)=\min_{k\in\mathbb N}\Big\{\sum_{i=1}^k\omega_i=n\Big\}\,.
$$