# Relationship between gamma and poisson identity

Tags: probability-distributions, proof-explanation, statistical-inference

> Let $X_1, \dots, X_n$ be a random sample from a Poisson population with parameter $\lambda$ and define $Y = \sum_i X_i$.  Y is sufficient for $\lambda$ and $Y \text{~} \text{Poisson}(n \lambda)$.
>
> **Identity:**  If $X \text{~ gamma($\alpha, \beta$)}$ for an integer $\alpha$, then for any $x$, $P(X \le x) = P(Y \ge \alpha)$ where $Y \text{~ Poission}(x/\beta)$.
>
> By the identity above, $P(Y \le y_0 | \lambda) = P(\chi^2_{2(y_0+1)} \gt 2n\lambda)$.

Can someone explain how the identity above shows this?  My thoughts were to put it into this form:

$P(X \le x) = P(Y \ge \alpha) \Rightarrow 1-P(X \le x) = 1-P(Y \ge \alpha)$

$\Rightarrow P(X \gt x) = P(Y \lt \alpha) \Rightarrow P(X \ge x) = P(Y \lt \alpha)$

But $P(Y \lt \alpha) \ne P(Y \le \alpha)$.

Comment: You may want to see [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2969484).

Comment: Can you elaborate?  I'm having trouble finding the answer to this question in the linked question.

Comment: See the 2nd-to-last line the of question statement: $\displaystyle F(t) =1 - \sum_{i=0}^{\alpha-1}{\frac {(\lambda t)^i} {i!}}e^{-\lambda t}$. The left hand side is exactly your $P(X \leq x)$, and the right hand side is exactly your $P(Y \geq \alpha)$. Note that for the Gamma distribution, your scale parameter $\beta$ is the inverse of the underlying rate of Poisson process $\displaystyle\frac1{\beta} = \lambda$. Your question is exactly the same as his.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2427795/321264, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4107340/321264