# Probability mass function of X (Poisson distribution) with random parameter λ (Uniform distribution)

Tags: probability-theory, random-variables

$X$ has Poisson distribution with parameter $λ$, and $λ$ is a random variable uniformly distributed over the interval $[0,2].$

Find the probability mass function of X with parameter λ. Find the probability that the value of variable is 2.

**My solution:**

I found the probability mass function of $X$, then $λ$ is not a random variable, and it is:
$G_x(t)=e^{{-λ}(1-t)}.$

Comment: Do you want a solution verification?

Comment: I want to understand how to solve this. I know it is easy, but I do not know how to do that.

Comment: In other words, the random variable $X$ conditioned on $[\Lambda=\lambda]$ has a Poisson$(\lambda)$ distribution, where $\Lambda$ itself is uniform over $[0,2]$. You are asked to find the distribution of $X$. Use total probability theorem.

Answer (score 1):

$$\mathbb{P}(X=t) = \int_0^2 \frac{e^{-\lambda}{\lambda}^t}{t!} \cdot \frac{1}{2} d\lambda = \frac{1}{2t!} \int_0^2 e^{-\lambda}{\lambda}^t d\lambda.$$

Can you complete the remaining steps?

(This involves the [incomplete Gamma function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Incomplete_gamma_function). I doubt your answer is correct because $\sum_{t=0}^\infty e^{-\lambda(1-t)}) \neq 1$.)

Answer (score 0):

$P[X=2]= \int_{0}^{2}{P[\Lambda =\lambda].P[X=2|\Lambda =\lambda]}d\lambda = \frac{1}{2\Gamma{3}}\int_{0}^{2}{e^{-\lambda}\lambda^{3-1}}d\lambda$

Now using the following [theorem](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/468001)

$\frac{1}{2\Gamma{3}}\int_{0}^{2}{e^{-\lambda}\lambda^{3-1}}d\lambda = \frac{1-5e^{-2}}{2}$