# Distribution of minimum of Uniform products

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions, uniform-distribution, poisson-distribution

I've been stuck on this question for a while.

> {$U_{i}$ iid, Uniform(0,1) 
> $V_{n} = \prod_{1}^{n} U_i$, n = 1, 2,... 
> $N = \min \{k: V_k < 0.1\} $ 
> Find the distribution of $N$

I know that this is supposed to be related somehow to a poisson distribution based off of other things that I have learnt, but that was with the summation of uniform distributions, not the product. I honestly just don't know where to begin. Any help would be very much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rewrite $N$ as $N=\min\{k:S_k>c\}$ where $S_k=-\ln V_k=-\sum\limits_{i=1}^k \ln U_i$ and $c=-\ln(0.1)$.

Then for $k\in \mathbb N$, $$\color{blue}{P(N-1\ge k)}=P(N>k)=P(S_1\le c,S_2\le c,\ldots,S_k\le c)=\color{green}{P(S_k\le c)}$$

Now $S_k$ is the sum of i.i.d Exponential$(1)$ variables $-\ln U_i$, [so that](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/655302/321264) $S_k$ has a certain Gamma distribution. Finally recall the [Gamma-Poisson relationship](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/467341/321264).