# Continuous Poisson Distribution

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, poisson-distribution

Is there a Continuous analogous of the Poisson Distribution? Under the analogous, I mean such a distribution that:

1. It is a one-parameter distribution
2. Its distribution function is similar to the Poisson one

Comment: See http://ac.inf.elte.hu/Vol_039_2013/137_39.pdf

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/467341/321264

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are different types of continuous extensions of Poisson distribution.

I favor the one presented in this paper:

"Continuous counterparts
of Poisson and binomial distributions
and their properties"
by [Andrii Ilienko](http://ac.inf.elte.hu/Vol_039_2013/137_39.pdf).

They are based on integral
representations of Poisson and binomial probability distribution functions using complete and incomplete (Euler) $\Gamma$ and $\operatorname{B}$ functions.

Answer (score 2):

I would like to complement the accepted answer by deriving again the Continuous Poisson distribution shown in the [paper](http://ac.inf.elte.hu/Vol_039_2013/137_39.pdf) of the accepted answer.
The derivation I show here is more natural although slightly less formal.

We will use an experiment to connect the distributions $\text{Poisson}(\lambda)$ whose domain is $k$, and $\text{Erlang}(k)$ whose domain is $\lambda$. Since the former is discrete and the latter is continuous, let's compare cumulative distribution functions. Shortening less and greater than with .lt and .gt, let $\text{Poisson}(\lambda)\text{.lt}(k)$ and $\text{Erlang}(k)\text{.gt}(\lambda)$ denote the probability that $X < k$ for $X\sim\text{Poisson}(\lambda)$ , and that $X > \lambda$ for $X\sim\text{Erlang}(k)$, respectively.

The experiment is a sequence of events that occur at $t_1, t_2, t_3, ...$ (in seconds), where $t_1 \sim \text{Exp}(1)$, $t_2 \sim t_1 + \text{Exp}(1)$, $t_3 \sim t_2 + \text{Exp}(1), ...$. In other words, $t_k \sim \text{Erlang}(k,1) = \text{Gamma}(k,1)$. This experiment is known as a [Poisson process](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_point_process) and to be more precise, I'm differing from the standard of a rate of $1/\lambda$ during one second by considering instead a fixed rate of 1 during $\lambda$ seconds. But these two points of view are equivalent.

Notice the following. $\text{Poisson}(\lambda)\text{.lt}(k)$ measures the probability that less than $k$ events occur during the first $\lambda$ seconds. **Equivalently**, this is the probability that the $k$'th event occurs after $\lambda$ seconds.
Therefore, this is the probability of $t_k>\lambda$, which coincides with $\text{Erlang}(k)\text{.gt}(\lambda)$.
Thus
$$ \text{Poisson}(\lambda)\text{.lt}(k) = \text{Erlang}(k)\text{.gt}(\lambda) $$

Let us now extend $\text{Poisson}(\lambda)$ into a $\text{Continuous-Poisson}(\lambda)$.
We know $\text{Gamma}(k)$ extends $\text{Erlang}(k)$ to non-integer values of $k$. This can informally still be thought of as waiting for the $k$'th event, as if events were fractioned in abstract manner by the $\text{Gamma}$ distribution. As a consequence, the Continuous-Poisson distribution can be naturally characterized with:
$$ \text{Continuous-Poisson}(\lambda)\text{.lt}(k) = \text{Gamma}(k)\text{.gt}(\lambda) $$

It's straightforward to get the CDF of our $\text{Continuous-Poisson}(\lambda)$ by plugging in the CDF of the [Gamma distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_distribution) from Wikipedia as
$$ \text{Continuous-Poisson}(\lambda)\text{.cdf}(k) := 1 - \frac{\gamma(k,\lambda)}{\Gamma(k)} = \frac{\Gamma(k,\lambda)}{\Gamma(k)} $$
where $\gamma$ and $\Gamma$ are the lower and upper [incomplete gamma functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Incomplete_gamma_function). This coincides with the formula in the [paper](http://ac.inf.elte.hu/Vol_039_2013/137_39.pdf) of the accepted answer. Regarding the PDF, we would need to compute the derivative of the CDF with respect to $k$, which looks difficult. The paper contains some formulas, although they contain integrals inside.

In terms of meaning, our CDF will measure the probability of having at most $k$ events until $\lambda$ seconds, where $k$ is possibly non-integer. Fractional events should be understood in the same abstract sense used by the Gamma distribution (a definition that mathematically makes sense, and maybe only mathematically).